# jquery add class and remove class on click

Tags: jquery

so this is my function for adding and removing but it only work for adding it doesnt remove on again click

```
(function ($) {
      $(".call-us-button .call").on("click", function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".phone-number").fadeIn();
        $(this).parent().find(".qr-code-call").fadeIn();
        $(this).parent().addClass("callBtnActive");
      });
    
      $(".call-us-button .call").on("click", function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".phone-number").fadeOut();
        $(this).parent().find(".qr-code-call").fadeOut();
        $(this).parent().removeClass("callBtnActive");
      });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Use one `click` event handler and use [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) to determine whether to fade in or out and whether to add or remove the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you need in a single event handler by using the [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) and [`fadeToggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) methods. In addition the code can be made more succint by chaining the methods and merging the class selectors.

```js
(function($) {
  $(".call-us-button .call").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent()
      .toggleClass("callBtnActive")
      .find(".phone-number, .qr-code-call").fadeToggle();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

As an aside, note that your code is wrapped in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), not a [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event handler. The two are not equivalent. It seems like your code is at least running so it's in the correct place in the DOM, but be aware this may not always be the case.

Comment: Ah, fadeToggle, I did not know that one. I thought I was clever with `[active ? "fadeOut" : "fadeIn"]()`